# Json data not able to display as a graph using sigma.js

Tags: javascript, json, sigma.js

I'm using this code to display JSON file data as a graph but it is not displaying anything.

How to display this JSON data using `sigma.js` in graph form.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

**Code**

```js
var data = {
  "UniversalWord": {
    "UniversalWord": [{
      "uw_id": 1,
      "HeadWord": {
        "word": "aare"
      },
      "Restriction": {
        "SemanticRelations": {
          "feat": [{
              "att": "restriction_type",
              "value": "iof"
            },
            {
              "att": "target",
              "val": " "
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "NLDescription": {
        "Gloss": {
          "feat": {
            "att": "Description",
            "val": "\"A RIVER IN NORTH CENTRAL SWITZERLAND THAT RUNS NORTHEAST INTO THE RHINE\""
          }
        },
        "Lemma": {
          "feat": {
            "att": "word",
            "val": "aare"
          }
        },
        "Example": {
          "feat": {
            "att": "description",
            "val": "\"\""
          }
        }
      },
      "MetaInfo": {
        "Frequency": {
          "freq": ""
        },
        "UWSource": {
          "Source_id": "WORDNET"
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}

// these are just some preliminary settings 
var g = {
  nodes: [],
  edges: []
};

// Create new Sigma instance in graph-container div (use your div name here) 
s = new sigma({
  graph: g,
  container: 'graph-container',
  renderer: {
    container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
    type: 'canvas'
  },
  settings: {
    minNodeSize: 8,
    maxNodeSize: 16
  }
});

// first you load a json with (important!) s parameter to refer to the sigma instance

sigma.parsers.json(
  //'test.json',
  data,
  s,
  function() {
    // this below adds x, y attributes as well as size = degree of the node 
    var i,
      nodes = s.graph.nodes(),
      len = nodes.length;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      nodes[i].x = Math.random();
      nodes[i].y = Math.random();
      nodes[i].size = s.graph.degree(nodes[i].id);
      nodes[i].color = nodes[i].center ? '#333' : '#666';
    }

    // Refresh the display:
    s.refresh();

    // ForceAtlas Layout
    s.startForceAtlas2();
  }
);
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.0/sigma.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.0/plugins/sigma.parsers.json.min.js"></script>

<div id="graph-container"></div>
```

Comment: Just a side note, you are loading sigma twice. Use either one. You are just wasting resources by loading both.

Comment: remove any one from this `<script src="sigma.js"></script>`, `<script src="sigma.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Rajesh Still it is not working!

Comment: @harishsharma i did it but not working yet!

Comment: @Nishita It was never suppose to. I said **a side note**. Its a good to have thing. Also, I tried to make your code runnable in stack snippet, but its failing. You should rectify it so that someone with proper knowledge can help you. :-)

Comment: Another side note: what you've shown here is not JSON. (JSON is the string you get when you serialise your object...)

Comment: @Rajesh ty for it!. :) But i m stuck on it. please provide me solution if you knowing.

Comment: @nnnnnn you can provide me possible changes to do for it. It will be very helpful for me

Comment: @Nishita Please note that we are here to help and you do not have to ask anyone to help you. If anyone knows the issue, we would provide it. Also next time please remember to tag any and every important library so your question gets exposure by relevant group. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh okie Sure! :)